# Horizontal Bootstrap Navbar is displaying vertically - why?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a portfolio page and want to use Bootstrap's horizontal navbar at the top of my pages.

However, it is displaying vertically instead.

http://elksie5000.pythonanywhere.com/portfolio

What have I got wrong?

Comment: follow this link https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Bootstrap version may need an update.

If you swap this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

With this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Your css will fix itself and your navbar will display properly.